confusion on palais smale condition
Let $F: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ functional on a Hilbert space $H$, satisfying Palais Smale Condition. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and put
$$
\begin{gathered}
F_\alpha:=\{v \in H: F(v)<\alpha\} \\
K_\alpha:=\{v \in H: F(v)=\alpha, D F(v)=0\}
\end{gathered}
$$
Let $\epsilon_0>0$ and a neighbourhood $U$ of $K_\alpha$ be given. Then there exist $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ and a continuous family
$$
\psi: H \times[0, \infty) \rightarrow H
$$
with the semigroup property $\psi(\psi(u, s), t)=\psi(u, s+t)$ for all $s, t \geq 0$, $u \in H$ and with
(i) $\psi(u, 0)=u$ for all $u \in H$
(ii) $F(\psi(u, t))$ is nonincreasing in $t$ for all $u \in H$
(iii) $\psi(u, t)=u$ for all $t$ whenever $D F(u)=0$, in particular for $u \in$ $K_\alpha$
(iv) $\psi(u, t)=u$ whenever $|F(u)-\alpha| \geq \epsilon_0$, for all $t$
(v) $\psi\left(F_{\alpha+\epsilon} \backslash U, 1\right) \subset F_{\alpha-\epsilon}, 
\psi\left(F_{\alpha+\epsilon}, 1\right) \subset F_{\alpha-\epsilon} \cup U$
(vi) If $F(u)$ is even (i.e. $F(u)=F(-u)$ for all $u$ ), then also $F(\psi(u, t))$ is even in $u$ for all $t($ i.e. $F(\psi(u, t))=F(\psi(-u, t)))$.
I am not understanding what condition (iv) and (v) is actually trying to say about the $\psi$ maps. I am not asking for proof, but details or some intuition, some idea on what is happening with this.
